# Get list of regex matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have string called line and I want to parse it using regex:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(line|LINE) (?<lineNr>\d+): (word|WORD) (?<Key_1>\w+) ( (?<e>(e1|e2)) (?<Key_2>\w+))* (?<s>\w+)$");
if (pattern.IsMatch(line))
{
    Match match = pattern.Match(line);
    int lineNr = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["lineNr"].Value);
    string Key_1 = match.Groups["Key_1"].Value;
    string e = match.Groups["e"].Value;
    string Key_2 = match.Groups["Key_2"].Value;
    string s = match.Groups["s"].Value;
}
```

I don't know "e" and "Key_2" repeat count and I want to add all of them to the array.
Is it possible to catch all of them?

//Edit

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(line|LINE) (?<lineNr>\d+): (word|WORD) (?<Key_1>\w+) ( (?<e>(e1|e2)) (?<Key_2>\w+))* (?<s>\w+)$");
Match match = pattern.Match(line);
if(match.Success)
{
        Regex p = new Regex(@" (?<e>(e1|e2)) (?<Key_2>\w+))");
        MatchCollection matches = p.Matches(line);
        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            string Key_2 = m.Groups["Key_2"].Value;
            string e = m.Groups["e"].Value;
            //add matches to array
        }

        int lineNr = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["lineNr"].Value);
        string Key_1 = match.Groups["Key_1"].Value;
        string s = match.Groups["s"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Currently, you are unnecessarily matching the string *twice*: First by your call to [`IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then again by invoking [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Instead, you may want to just call `Match`, and on the returned `Match` instance, check the value of the [`Success` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find out whether there were any matches. And then of course what @hwnd said.

Comment: Just simply use the Regex.Match method here, if you have multiple strings use .Matches method.

Comment: Thank you. Can you look at edited post and say if that's what you meant?

Comment: Can you provide this non-existent string `line` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
var newArray = pattern.Matches( line ).OfType<Match>.Select( m => new { e = m.Groups["e"].Value, Key_2 = m.Groups["Key_2"].Value } ).ToArray();
```